# ggplot2 is incorrectly sorting the X axis of my graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot of user login behavior for a two month period. I used the `qplot` function from the `ggplot2` package, and with the following code

`qplot(date_time, login_count, data=client_login_clean)`

I plotted `login_count` over time as shown below. Unfortunately, the y-axis, `num_records` is sorted such that the first five tick marks on the y-axis are 1, 10, 106, 11, and 12, rather than 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Could someone let me know how to fix this?

[image: User logins over time]

Comment: `login_count` is likely a factor variable rather than numeric. You really should post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when asking for help to verify.

Answer (score 3):

That's because, for some reason, your `login_count` variable is a character vector. ggplot internally coerces all character vectors to factors, with labels ordered alphabetically, and then sorts the axis according to that order.

I also think I know why this happened: `"num_records"` is actually a value in your `login_count` column, so the whole thing has been coerced to a character vector. Delete that element and use `as.numeric`, then the ordering should be correct. This is a good opportunity to read over your data loading/generating process and make sure you haven't made any other mistakes. Sometimes the tiniest bugs can uncover massive problems you would never have noticed otherwise.

As a side note, this is why you should be careful with `character`-class variables and ggplot plotting. You can save yourself a lot of headaches by explicitly specifying a factor ordering up front.

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly have your variable encoded as a factor rather than an integer.  Try `login_count <- as.numeric( as.character( login_count ) )` then run it again.  An alternative is `taRifx::destring`.

As a side note, a wizard never mis-sorts his axis.  He sorts it precisely as he means to.

Comment: ggplot is a highly opinionated and very stubborn wizard.